# Camel ActiveMQ client blocking, temp storage usage immediately hits 100%

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, spring-integration

I'm seeing 100% utilisation of activemq's temp storage (configured to be 100mb), and the activemq client is blocking. This 100% usage remains permanently, and I have no idea what's going on

I have a camel route, which consumes from a queue (QUEUE.IN) using the JmsTransactionManager.

```
public final class RouteUnderTest extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("activemq-transacted:QUEUE.IN")
                .bean(myBean)
                .to("activemq:QUEUE.OUT");
    }
}
```

While processing the message from this queue I'm invoking a spring-integration client (myBean) which is configured as follows

```
<int:gateway id="myBean" service-interface="MyBean">
    <int:method name="request" request-channel="channel"/>
</int:gateway>

<int:chain input-channel="channel">
    <int:transformer ref="transformedToJsonHere"/>
    <jms:outbound-gateway request-destination-name="QUEUE.MYBEAN"
                          receive-timeout="5000"
                          explicit-qos-enabled="true"
                          time-to-live="5000"
                          delivery-persistent="false"/>
    <int:transformer ref="transformedToAnObjectHere"/>
</int:chain>
```

My broker is configured to use LevelDB, and with the following usage limits:

```
<persistenceAdapter>
    <levelDB directory="${activemq.data}/leveldb"/>
</persistenceAdapter>

<systemUsage>
    <systemUsage>
        <memoryUsage>
            <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70"/>
        </memoryUsage>
        <storeUsage>
            <storeUsage limit="500 mb"/>
        </storeUsage>
        <tempUsage>
            <tempUsage limit="100 mb"/>
        </tempUsage>
    </systemUsage>
</systemUsage>
```

When my route consumes the message and then attempts to put a non-persistent message on QUEUE.OUT the client is blocked and my broker shows 100% usage of temp storage.

[image: broker web console]

And I see the following activemq logs

```
2015-07-28 15:44:59,678 | INFO  | Usage(default:temp:queue://QUEUE.MYBEAN:temp) percentUsage=0%, usage=104857600, limit=104857600, percentUsageMinDelta=1%;Parent:Usage(default:temp) percentUsage=100%, usage=104857600, limit=104857600, percentUsageMinDelta=1%: Temp Store is Full (0% of 104857600). Stopping producer (ID:orbit-vm-55561-1438094698190-1:1:3:1) to prevent flooding queue://QUEUE.MYBEAN. See http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html for more info (blocking for: 1s) | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ NIO Worker 6
```

The queues look like (You can see that the QUEUE.IN message has been not been dequeued because it's still being processed transactionally, and no message has gone to QUEUE.MYBEAN)
[image]

I can fix this problem with any one of the following approaches:

1. Use KahaDB instead of LevelDB
2. Increase temp storage limit (150MB seems to do it but I haven't experimented a great deal)
3. Configure tempDataStore in activemq.xml (see below)

When configuring the tempDataStore it looks like:

```
<tempDataStore> 
    <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.leveldb.LevelDBStore"> 
        <property name="directory" value="${activemq.data}/tmp" /> 
    </bean> 
</tempDataStore>
```

I should add, we were using KahaDB previously and this worked fine, but the upgrade to LevelDB has exposed this issue. Reverting to KahaDB is not an option.

I'm hoping someone could explain what we're seeing here, as the results are really difficult to understand. Why does using LevelDB necessitate a higher temp usage limit?, and why does configuring the tempDataStore explicitly also fix the problem?

*I don't fully understand what's going on here so I'm worried that simply increasing the temp usage limit a little will just hide the problem until a later date.*

**Versions:**

- **ActiveMQ**: 5.11.1
- **Camel**: 2.14.0
- **Spring**: 4.0.8.RELEASE
- **Spring Integration**: 4.0.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 2):

We ran into exactly the same issue with ActiveMQ 5.13.2

The solution when using LevelDB is to **explicitly configure a dedicated `tempDataStore`**  as you did.

If not, the broker uses the same store (LevelDB) for both persistent (persistent usage) and non-persistent messages (temp usage). You may therefore end-up in situations where the broker doesn't accept any non-persistent message anymore just because the store already holds persistent ones up to the configured `tempUsage` limit. It will however accept persistent ones if your `storeUsage` limit is set higher...

When using KahaDB, the broker automatically uses another store for the non-persistent messages (created in the tmp directory). So you don't have the problem...

Look at the following code for more indepth information: https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/activemq-5.13.2/activemq-broker/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/broker/BrokerService.java#L1739

When reading that code, remember LevelDBStore implements `PListStore`, but KahaDBStore doesn't...